# MS SQL scalar function to format datebased on language switch

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, date-format, scalar

I have created a scalar function that is supposed to spit out a date in a specific format based on a variable.
for some reason i get an error around the "else"

what am i doing wrong ?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetDateformat] (@datum datetime,@CNotation char(2))
/*    accepts datum and CNotation
USAGE:
select fGetDateformat(datum, "EN" or "DE")    */
returns varchar(25) AS
BEGIN
declare @ReturnStr varchar(25)
if @Cnotation = 'DE'
set language german
set @ReturnStr = 
DATENAME(dd, @datum)+'. '+DATENAME(MM, @datum)+' '+ DATENAME(YEAR, @datum)
else
set @ReturnStr = DATENAME(mm, @datum)+' '+DATENAME(dd, @datum)+', '+ DATENAME(YEAR, @datum) 
return @ReturnStr
END
GO
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? If you are on 2012 you can simply use the format function.

Comment: This seems very much like something that should be handled in your application layer and not in SQL. You also cannot set the language within a function, your will get the following error: `Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET COMMAND' within a function.` If this must be done in SQL I'd suggest a calendar table with columns for different countries date formats, then you can do something like `CASE WHEN @Cnotation = 'DE' THEN GermanDateString WHEN @Cnotation = 'US' THEN USDateString ELSE DefaultDateString END`

Comment: very much agree that it should be handled in the application layer. i´m using a legal case management system which offers sql as a scripting environment for letter generation. Application layer does not offer access to their formatting here (they do elsewhere), so i´m stuck with SQL. had been thinking about a calendar table, but wanted to avoid the effort by using the set language command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a T-SQL block spans multiple lines, you have to enclose it in `begin` and `end`.  For example, this won't work:

```
if 1=1
    print 'One is one!'
    print 'Yay'
else
    print 'Huh?'
```

This will:

```
if 1=1
    begin
    print 'One is one!'
    print 'Yay'
    end
else
    print 'Huh?'
```

Note that `print 'Huh?'` is still okay, since it is a single line.